# Python namespaces and import: setting the value of a global variable in an imported module creates a second, unrelated global?

Tags: python, python-3.x

(Python 3.6)

Consider a package **odd** with two modules **foo** and **bar**. I want a customer of **odd** to use a single import for everything in the package, without having to know what's defined in foo and what's defined in bar. So I define an **__init__.py** with the following:

```
from .foo import *
from .bar import *
```

**foo.py** contains a global variable **baz** and a function **set_baz()** that sets the value of baz, as follows:

```
baz = 12

def set_baz():
    global baz 
    print('Baz was {}'.format(baz))
    baz = 13
    print('Now it is changed to {}'.format(baz))
```

When I import **odd** (from elsewhere) and look at the value of **odd.baz**, I get what I expect, the original value of 12.

```
In [2]: import odd

In [3]: odd.baz
Out[3]: 12
```

But when I run **set_baz()**, it does not change the value of **odd.baz**, as expected, but instead changes a different global variable: **odd.foo.baz**.

```
In [4]: odd.set_baz()
Baz was 12
Now it is changed to 13

In [5]: odd.baz
Out[5]: 12

In [6]: odd.foo.baz
Out[6]: 13
```

Apparently there are two unrelated namespaces, one for **odd** and one for **odd.foo**, and each namespace defines **baz**, differently.

How can I accomplish what I want, a single global variable, accessed by customers of odd as **odd.baz**?

(And yes, I know that I should not be using global variables like this. I have distilled the reasonable goal I am actually trying to accomplish into this silly example with **odd.baz** that illustrates the underlying problem.)

Comment: try nonlocal instead of global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has names, not variables.
If you import `odd.foo.baz` in `odd.__init__`, it will create a new name `odd.__init__.baz` pointing to the same `int` object `12`.
If you change the name `odd.foo.baz` to point to another `int`, `13`, this has no effect whatsoever on the name `odd.__init__.baz`.

Such quirks are one of the reasons why globals are considered bad practice (except very special cases).

You can solve the issue by encapsulating `baz` in a mutable object, like a `dict`:

`odd.foo.py`:

```
GLOBALS = {'baz': 12}

def set_baz():
    print('Baz was {}'.format(GLOBALS['baz']))
    GLOBALS['baz'] = 13
    print('Now it is changed to {}'.format(GLOBALS['baz']))

def get_baz():
    return GLOBALS['baz']
```

To make a name `baz` that behaves similar to a `int`, you can use [`werkzeug.local.LocalProxy`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/local/#werkzeug.local.LocalProxy):

```
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy

baz = LocalProxy(lambda: GLOBALS['baz'])
```

Example:

```
>>> test.baz
12
>>> test.set_baz()
Baz was 12
Now it is changed to 13
>>> test.baz
13
>>> test.baz + 4
17
>>> test.baz.__class__
<class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy'>
```

Comment: In short: "from .foo import *" does not expose the names from the imported module into the importing module. Rather "from .foo import *" creates new names in the importing module, new names that initially take the same value as the corresponding names in the imported module. Now I understand. Thanks.